# Hassle Free Code structuring for Angular 4 project with shared components between different projects

Tags: angular, optimization, angular-cli, webpack-2

We got a problem with code structuring in our new project. The requirement follows below.

We got 3 projects Project A, Project B, Project C. Also All projects have same look & feel(UX).

Project A it is a basic Angular 4 Project which is created using angular-cli & It is about to complete & It will have a enhancements & bug fixing phase once it is delivered.
Project B is nested under Project A as a module and its not yet started.
Project B & C uses design & components from Project A.

Now, How can we create a structure which will have shared components between 3 projects & Any enhancement or bug fixing on shared components should not impact any part of all three projects. We have a team of different expertise on Angular 4.

Thanks,
Sampat

Comment: I don't think this is possible: `Any enhancement or bug fixing on shared components should not impact any part of all three projects.` How could the shared components have edits/bug fixes that don't impact any of the projects that use those shared components? I guess you could put in the change but not recompile? But then what is the point?

Comment: Hi @DeborahK, Thanks for your question, What I mean to say is there any way for code structuring to have shared components without impacting the other projects. Like versioning in Components(I don't know it is possible or not)